# Deleting Line from text file php

Tags: php

i am trying to list all of the lines in a text file and have a delete button next to each one. When the button is pressed that line should be deleted. like below

```
 Line One Text | Delete
 Line Two Text | Delete
 Line Three Text | Delete
```

I think i am quite close but cannot get it to work, any ideas why? The lines and buttons display fine, but the delete button does not seem to do anything.

edit.php

```
<?php
$textFile = file("guestbook.txt");
foreach ($textFile as $key => $val) {
    $line = @$line . $val
        . "<input type='submit' name=$key value='Delete'><br />";
}

$form = "<form name='form' method='post' action='deleter.php'> $line 
    </form>";

echo $form;
?>
```

deleter.php

```
if ($delete != "" && $delete > !$lines || $delete === '0') {
    $textFile[$delete] = "";
    $fileUpdate = fopen("data.txt", "wb");
    for ($a = 0; $a < $lines; $a++) {
        fwrite($fileUpdate, $textFile[$a]);
    }
    fclose($fileUpdate);
    header("Location:edit.php");
    exit;
}

foreach ($textFile as $key => $val) {
    $line = @$line . $val . "<a href =?delete=$key> Delete </a><br />";
}
echo $line;
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a line from the file with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712878/how-to-delete-a-line-from-the-file-with-php)

Comment: Storing a guestbook in a text file is probably not a good idea. What if 2 people are trying to edit the guestbook at the same time, the whole file will need to be locked, or you risk corruption. If I were you I would use a database. Most php installations come with MySQL

Comment: Guestbook is a loose term, its for the websites owner to upload their own reviews given to them in a physical guestbook.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to query the server with the string to be removed if no line can be equal to another one, e.g., `delete.php?str=<your string>` and do the deletion of that string (note that I said 'string' not line).

If it's possible for lines to be equal, you should identify the lines and follow a similar approach: `delete.php?line=<number>`.

This should be easy and you could write a flexible code that deletes lines from a giving file by also passing the filename.

Edit: Example provided following the advise of using a hidden field.

```
<?php
$html = "<form id='form' method='post' action='delete.php'>";
foreach(array("line 1", "line 2", "line 3") as $key => $value ) {
    $html .= "<span>${value}</span>";
    $html .= "<input type='hidden' name='lineNumber' value='${key}'>";
    $html .= "<input type='submit' value='Delete' name='line'><br>";
}
$html .= "</form>";
echo $html;
?>
```

In your `delete.php` get the content of `$_POST['lineNumber']` to retrieve the line number.

Comment: Thanks very much, will give it a go now and report back.

Comment: @loveforfire33 if you are using `JavaScript` you can change the `action` attribute dynamically. If you are planning on using it, `JQuery` will help you a lot while submitting the form and also by changing the `action` attribute. Just ask for it and I'll happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have some JavaScript which loops through each input and appends each value to a hidden form field. When the form is submitted simply get the value of that form field and overwrite the file with that value.