# Php fopen delete each readed line while reading

Tags: php

I have a code

```
$handle = fopen(getcwd() . "/emails.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        SendEmails($line,$strSubject,$strMessage,$txtFormName,$txtFormEmail,$fname,$ftype,$tmp_path);
        $line.delete; // here i need to delete each readed line
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "error opening the file.";
}
```

How to delete each readed line while reading?

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712878/how-to-delete-a-line-from-the-file-with-php

Comment: Because something wrong with execution and fopen start to duplicate lines, i think this hapens when browser timeout is. So if there was empty string fopen read them but i need only filed strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$handle = fopen(getcwd() . "/emails.txt", "r");
$readedlines="";
if ($handle) {
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
SendEmails($line,$strSubject,$strMessage,$txtFormName,$txtFormEmail,$fname,$ftype,$tmp_path);
   $readedlines=$readedlines.$line;
fclose($handle);
$newFileContent=str_replace($readedlines,"",file_get_contents($filename));
$handle=fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($handle,$newFileContent);
fclose($handle);
} else {
echo "error opening the file.";
 }
```

I mean just concate all readed line into one string and replace through the whole string of file content.
Hope that helps

Comment: okay that mean you want to delete line while `while loop` is running ?.

Comment: OP said that but seems like your answer is enough for him.

Comment: It will work for some cases as described by the OP - but its neither a general solution to the problem described nor an elegant one.

Comment: May be with two handlers run parallel can solve the problem. means $handle1=fopen(filename."r"); and $handle2=fopen("filename","w"); and use them both in one while loop

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get file contents
$contents = file_get_contents('/emails.txt');

// Explode to get contents in an array
$rows = explode("\n", $contents);

file_put_contents('/emails.txt', "");

// Loop through all rows in emails.txt
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // If sending the email fails, add row to $notSent
    if (false === SendEmails($row, $strSubject, $strMessage, $txtFormName, $txtFormEmail, $fname, $ftype,$tmp_path)) {
        $contents = file_get_contents('/emails.txt');
        $contents .= $row."\n";
        file_put_contents('/emails.txt', $contents);
    }
}
```

Comment: Once again - if script breaks in a `foreach` - nothing will be written to your file.